# Change Bootstrap carousel dot indicators to squares

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to change the little dot indicators on a Bootstrap 3 carousel to squares. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the `border-radius` to `0` on `.carousel-indicators li`

Answer (score 1):

I would look here to change the shapes of those indicators:

```
.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -30%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000 \9;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```